# store a lambda that captures this

Tags: c++17

Using C++ 17, I'm looking for a way to store a lambda that captures the this pointer, without using `std::function<>`. The reason to not using `std::function<>` is that I need the guaranty that no dynamic memory allocations are used. The purpose of this, is to be able to define some asynchronous program flow. Example:

```cpp
    class foo {
    public:
        void start() {
           timer(1ms, [this](){
               set_pin(1,2);
               timer(1ms, [this](){
                   set_pin(2,1);
               }
           }
        }
    private:
        template < class Timeout, class Callback >
        void timer( Timeout to, Callback&& cb ) {
            cb_ = cb;
            // setup timer and call cb_ one timeout reached
            ...
        }

        ??? cb_;
    };
```

Edit: Maybe it's not really clear: `std::function<void()>` would do the job, but I need / like to have the guaranty, that no dynamic allocations happens as the project is in the embedded field. In practice `std::function<void()>` seems to not require dynamic memory allocation, if the lambda just captures this. I guess this is due to some small object optimizations, but I would like to not rely on that.

Comment: It isn't clear why you need a lambda or an std::function or a member template. What exactly is hidden behind the `setup timer` comment?

Comment: Well to store the function / action to be called, once the timer expires. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Your example only ever calls `timer` twice. Instead of lambdas, write two "normal" member functions, and have `timer` store a pointer-to-member.

Comment: I have asked to show what exactly hapens in "setup timer", this is not accidental. What arguments do you pass to this timer setup function? You almost certainly cannot pass it a lambda.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well, that is the nature of an example. I reality the member functions would be most likely all one liners and there would be dozens who all require names like `set_reset_pin_to_high_set_up_timer_for_10ms()`. That's why I'm looking for a `std::function<>` replacement.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Sure, why shouldn't I be able to pass a lambda to `timer()`. The crucial part is really the assignment in `timer()`.

Comment: I'm asking you for the third time. What is "setup timer"? Show what you are doing there. Show, don't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own `function_lite` to store the lambda, then you can use `static_assert` to check the size and alignment requirements are satisfied:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>

class function_lite {
  static constexpr unsigned buffer_size = 16;

  using trampoline_type = void (function_lite::*)() const;

  trampoline_type trampoline;
  trampoline_type cleanup;
  alignas(std::max_align_t) char buffer[buffer_size];

  template <typename T>
  void trampoline_func() const {
    auto const obj =
        std::launder(static_cast<const T*>(static_cast<const void*>(buffer)));
    (*obj)();
  }

  template <typename T>
  void cleanup_func() const {
    auto const obj =
        std::launder(static_cast<const T*>(static_cast<const void*>(buffer)));
    obj->~T();
  }

 public:
  template <typename T>
  function_lite(T t)
      : trampoline(&function_lite::trampoline_func<T>),
        cleanup(&function_lite::cleanup_func<T>) {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) <= buffer_size);
    static_assert(alignof(T) <= alignof(std::max_align_t));

    new (static_cast<void*>(buffer)) T(t);
  }

  ~function_lite() { (this->*cleanup)(); }

  function_lite(function_lite const&) = delete;
  function_lite& operator=(function_lite const&) = delete;

  void operator()() const { (this->*trampoline)(); }
};

int main() {
  int x = 0;
  function_lite f([x] {});
}
```

Note: this is not copyable; to add copy or move semantics you will need to add new members like `trampoline` and `cleanup` which can properly copy the stored object.

Answer (score 2):

There is no drop in replacement in the language or the standard library.

Every lambda is a unique type in the typesystem. Technically you may have a lambda as a member, but then its type is fixed. You may not assign other lambdas to it.

If you really want to have an owning function wrapper like `std::function`, you need to write your own. Actually you want a `std::function` with a big enough small-buffer-optimization buffer.

Another approach would be to omit the this capture and pass it to the function when doing the call. So you have a captureless lambda, which is convertible to a function pointer which you can easily store. I would take this route and adapter complexer ways if really nessessary.

it would look like this (i trimmed down the code a bit):

```
class foo 
{
public:
    void start() 
    {
       timer(1, [](foo* instance)
       { 
           instance->set_pin(1,2); 
       });
    }

private:    
    template < class Timeout, class Callback >
    void timer( Timeout to, Callback&& cb ) 
    {
        cb_ = cb;
        cb_(this); // call the callback like this
    }  

    void set_pin(int, int)
    {
        std::cout << "pin set\n";
    }

    void(*cb_)(foo*);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought about that solution and rejected it, because it doesn't allow access to the private parts of the class. But in general, it's a good solution.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki I may be wrong but i think it has access to the private parts (set_pin is private for example).

Comment: I will give it a try!